# pass header parameter in stripe subscription api

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am creating subscription in stripe, and want to take money on behalf of connected account.

Here is the code i am writing to make subscription

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($client->stripe_customer);
$subscription = $customer->subscriptions->create(array(
            "plan" => $plan->id
        ));
```

That is allowing me to create stripe subscription to respective user. Now i want to pass header in this request how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

From your syntax, it looks like you might be using an older version of the Stripe bindings here. If you intend to use the Stripe Account header you'll need to update to a newer branch. As a note this comes with a newer, namespaced syntax so you'll need to make some code updates as well. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

If you're trying to create a subscription on a connected account you'll also need to ensure that the customer is there! You can use the shared customers flow to copy customers from your Platform if need be, https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers

Once you have a customer on the connected account you'll want to use the Stripe-Account header, like this:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header

You can retrieve a customer like this:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve(
array("id"=> "cus_xxxxyyyyzzzz"),
array("stripe_account" => "acct_xxxyyyzzzz")
);
```

And you can create a subscription like this:

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
  "customer" => "cus_9DxlCLITQDBPwe",
  "plan" => "platinum-trial"
),array("stripe_account" => "acct_xxxyyyzzzz"));
```

If you'd like to continue to use the 1.x branch of the PHP bindings you'll need to use the access token rather than the account header, as outlined here, https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-api-keys